# Prove that $E' - F' \subset (E-F)'$, where $E$ and $F$ are subsets of a metric space.

Tags: general-topology

Notation: E' is the set of limit points of E.

To prove that one set is a subset of the other, we need to prove that elements of the subset also belong to the superset.

Begin proof:

Let $p \in (E' - F') \implies p \in E' \wedge p \notin F'$. So p is a limit point of $E$ but not of $F$. $\implies B_r(p) \cap E - \{p\} \neq \emptyset$ and $B_r(p) \cap F - \{p\} = \emptyset$. Consider a nonempty set $A$. $A - \emptyset = A$. Therefore we have: $B_r(p) \cap E - \{p\} - (B_r(p) \cap F - \{p\}) \neq \emptyset \implies B_r(p) \cap E - B_r(p) \cap F \neq \emptyset$.

Consider sets $A, B$, and $C$. $A \cap B - A \cap C.$ We hope to prove that this is equal to $A \cap (B - C)$. $x \in A \cap B - A \cap C \iff (x \in A \cap B) \wedge (x \notin A \cap C) \iff (x \in A \wedge x \in B) \wedge (x \notin A \vee x \notin C) \iff (x \in A \wedge (x \notin A \vee x \notin C)) \wedge (x \in B \wedge (x \notin A \vee x \notin C)) \iff (x \in A-C) \wedge (x \in B-C) \iff x \in A-C \cap B-C.$

Hmm, can someone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a sequence approach might be helpful.

Let $p\in (E'-F')$. Then $p$ is a limit point of $E$, but not of $F$. Thus, there is a sequence $\{a_n\}\subseteq E$ which converges to $p$, but since $p\notin F'$ there is no such sequence in $F$.

Pretend that for every $M\in \mathbb{N}$ $\exists$ $x_m\in F$ s.t. $x_m=a_{k_m}$ for some $k_m\in\mathbb{N}, k_m\geq M$. Then $\{x_m\}\to p$ which obviously contradicts $p\notin F'$. Thus, there is some $M\in\mathbb{N}$ for which $a_n\in (E-F)$ $\forall$ $n>M$.

This immediately implies that $\{a_{n+M}\}\subseteq(E-F)$. Since $\{a_{n+M}\}\to p$, then $p\in (E-F)'$.